# How can I keep the data of a form in my javascript if the submit button reloads the page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I have a simple form with 2 text, 1 number and 1 radio inputs, and I'm trying to take that data into my javascript to create an array of objects created with a constructor, but in the moment I hit the submit button and console log the array it appears empty, I suppose because of the reloading of the page, but I'm not sure.

Here is my javascript code:

```js
let myLibrary = []; //the array I wantd to fill with the objects
const form = document.querySelector('#form'); //the form itself

// the constructor
function Book (title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;
}

// the submit listener, which takes the data of the form and sends it as argument of the function that pushes the new object to the array
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.target).entries());
    addBookToLibrary(data);
});

function addBookToLibrary (data) {
    myLibrary.push(new Book(data.title, data.author, data.pages, data.read));
}
```

I've tried applying the preventDefault() method to the submit button but that stop the submitting of the form. I also tried doing it with FormData() but I had the same issue.

Comment: Store the data in local storage or session storage, and retrieve it from there on page load.

Answer (score 0):

What I did:

1. Changed the submit button and add a regular button type button to prevent the page to reload.
2. Take the data of the form with the "elements" property of the HTML form, which returns a list of all the form controls and can be accessed with an index -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements
3. Create the objects passing the "value" attribute of each element as arguments of the constructor, and push it into the array
4. Create a click listener for the button, and call the function that creates the objects.

```js
let myLibrary = [];
const data = document.querySelector('#form').elements;  // HTMLFormElement.elements
const btnSubmit = document.querySelector('#btnSubmit'); // Button type button

function Book (title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;
}

// Take the "value" of each element of the form and create a new Book object
function addBookToLibrary (data) {
    myLibrary.push(new Book(data[0].value, data[1].value, data[2].value, data[3].value));
    console.log(myLibrary);
}

// The listener that calls the function
btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    addBookToLibrary(data);
});
```